# Virtualmin + Nginx + SSL setup error with cloudflare 521

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Installed Virtualmin + Nginx + PHP-FPM

Everything set up fine, however, when I installed SSL Certificate 3 month’s trial (Fully Valid Cert) not from Letsencrypt ( Reached limit ) everything works perfectly but, when I switch to Cloudflare my website crashed with 521 server not found. Tried switching to a different option like Flexible, Full, Full (strict) with no luck

command

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

got a bunch of errors in the log file.

```
root@server:~# tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

2020/12/29 21:59:05 [emerg] 6813#6813: bind() to 2xx.2xx.xx3.xxx:443 failed (98: Address already in use)

2020/12/29 21:59:05 [emerg] 6813#6813: bind() to [2xxx:a1xx:xxxx:8xxx::1]:443 failed (98: Address already in use)

2020/12/29 21:59:05 [emerg] 6813#6813: still could not bind()

2020/12/29 22:31:47 [emerg] 512#512: cannot load certificate “/home/example/ssl.cert”: BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen(’/home/example/ssl.cert’,‘r’) error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

2020/12/29 22:32:37 [emerg] 1986#1986: cannot load certificate “/home/example/ssl.cert”: BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen(’/home/example/ssl.cert’,‘r’) error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)

2020/12/29 23:58:45 [alert] 12025#12025: *1168 open socket #17 left in connection 93

2020/12/29 23:58:45 [alert] 12025#12025: aborting
```

I’m pretty sure those SSL files are there but nginx thinks something else ;(

This is the output I get

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      678/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1722/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19353/perl          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19330/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1722/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15079/systemd-resol 
tcp        0      0 207.244.253.107:53      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      575/named           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      575/named           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      630/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11000         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1044/lookup-domain- 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1722/master         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      575/named           
tcp        0      0 207.244.253.107:443     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19330/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19398/perl          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      678/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      542/postgrey --pidf 
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      1722/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      8361/proftpd: (acce 
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN      19353/perl          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19330/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      1722/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      8361/proftpd: (acce 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      575/named           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      630/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1722/master         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      575/named           
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      787/dovecot         
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10023               :::*                    LISTEN      542/postgrey --pidf 
root@server:~#
```

And yes the files are there and permission are set chmod 600

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly some program is listen port 443.
You can found which program listen port 443 with `netstat -ltnp` command.
If the netstat is not found your server, install net-tools package.

Secondly nginx cannot access your certificate. `/home/example/ssl.cert`
Check this certificates are there ? If they are stay at there, check the file permission.

Comment: I've edited my question with the output above

Comment: `lsof -i :80,443` helps to find what is blocking, but remind that private related questions have to be asked on superuser.com

Comment: thanks, i will use this command to see what's going on with 443